# Link selection on Opera Mini 4.2 acting strangely

Tags: html, css, opera, mobile-website

I'm developing a mobile site in HTML for use on 2 Blackberry models, one quite old (8700v) and one newer (8520) as specified by the client.

The native browser on the 8520 is rendering my HTML/CSS pages perfectly. The native browser on the old 8700 is far from perfect however as the CSS support is minimal.

As a solution I decided to try installing Opera Mini 4.2 on the 8700. The rendering is great, speed is even improved but there's some rather strange behaviour happening with the hyperlinks on the page.

When I scroll down through my pages links are automatically highlighted and made ready for selection. This is fine until I have a number of links close together, for example in my nav menu. The nav menu is a set of links arranged within a . When I scroll to the menu all the links within the menu highlight at once. Even within the body if 2 links are on 2 separate lines (one  stacked on top of another) the same issue appears.

I'm trawling Opera documentation but haven't found anything useful yet. Anyone got any ideas on why this happens and if it can be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the actual HTML/CSS code, it's hard to pinpoint the exact cause of this, but it's most likely one of the following:

1. The links in question point to the same URL. The browser will highlight them as a group to visualize this.
2. Some script is adding a click event listener or similar to the group of links.
3. An <a>-tag has been left open.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! I don't have any real content in there yet so all my links were <a href="#"> and that was the issue. Once they link to different pages it's all fine. Many thanks!